# Browse, import, and append excel tabs to Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2007 database called BusRoutes with two tables in it called Routes and Stops. I also have several excel spreadsheets that are based on an excel template that are populated by the drivers. These spreadsheets should always have the same format but not the same file names.  I am trying to create a button that will perform the following actions:

Allow the user to navigate to the excel spreadsheet, select the “Bus Routes” tab, and append all the data to the “Routes” Access table.

Navigate to the same excel spreadsheet and select the “Bus Stop” tab and append all the data to the Access “Stops” table.

The excel spreadsheets could be stored anywhere. I have no control over where on the driver’s computer he or she stores the excel spreadsheets.

The spreadsheet names will differ as their naming conventions’ are based on the route number and school year they are driven.

The excel spreadsheets header names exactly match the corresponding table field names they are getting imported into. Tab names and header info are not alterable in the spreadsheet.

Spreadsheets could be either 2003 or 2007 versions.

Oh and "e-mail_add" is a hyperlink is that makes any difference.

I know that I have to use TransferSpreadsheets Action to append the data but I am at a loss as to how to navigate to the spreadsheet, select the individual tabs, and pass this variable to the TransferSpreadsheets action.

I tried this as an attempt to at least try to return a file name value but bombed out at the second line with following error: Run time error-2147467259(80004005)': Method 'FileDialog' of aobject'_Application' failed.

```
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

dlg.Title = "Select Excel Spreadsheet to import"
dlg.AllowMultiSelect = False
dataPath = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
Me!browseDataPath = dataPath
MsgBox("File is " & dataPath, vbOKOnly, "Check file name")

End If
```

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty straightforward to use a simple form like this:

[image]

with code behind it that is something along these lines

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
    Dim dlg As Object  ' FileDialog
    Dim sheetList As String, i As Long
    Dim xlApp As Object  ' Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object  ' Excel.Workbook

    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(3)  ' msoFileDialogFilePicker
    dlg.Title = "Select Excel Document to import"
    dlg.Filters.Clear
    dlg.Filters.Add "Excel documents", "*.xls*", 1
    dlg.AllowMultiSelect = False
    dlg.Show
    If dlg.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Me.browseDataPath.Value = dlg.SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Me.browseDataPath.Value)
        sheetList = ""
        For i = 1 To xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count
            sheetList = sheetList & ";" & xlWorkBook.Sheets(i).Name
        Next
        Me.lstSheets.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.lstSheets.RowSource = Mid(sheetList, 2)
        xlWorkBook.Close
        Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
    End If
    Set dlg = Nothing
End Sub
```

All you need to do now is add an "OK" button to use the values of the Text Box and the List Box selection to call `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **'This code goes behind the button which imports the file**

    Option Compare Database

    Private Sub Command2_Click()

    Dim s_Filter As String
        Dim s_InputFileName As String

        s_Filter = ahtAddFilterItem(s_Filter, "Excel Files (*.XLSX)", "*.XLSX")
        s_InputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                                Filter:=s_Filter, OpenFile:=True, _
                                DialogTitle:="Please select an input file...", _
                                Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

        Me.Text0.Value = s_InputFileName

    '------------code for importing----------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Excel variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlFile As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
    Dim xlRange1 As Excel.Range

    'Get the info from Excel:
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(s_InputFileName)
    filepath = RTrim(LTrim(Me.Text0.Value))

    With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    With .Workbooks(.Workbooks.Count)
    For i = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
    WrksheetName = .Worksheets(i).Name

    Set xlSheet = xlFile.Sheets(WrksheetName)
    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("AA5")
    Set xlRange1 = xlSheet.Range("A65536")

    lcolumn = xlRange.End(xltoleft).Address
    lrow = xlRange1.End(xlUp).Row

    lcol = Mid(lcolumn, 2, 1)


    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, WrksheetName, filepath, True, WrksheetName & "!A5:" & lcol & lrow

    Next i
    'Next i
    End With
    End With
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlFile = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlRange = Nothing
    Set xlRange1 = Nothing

    End Sub

****'Then paste this code to a module****

'--------Code to be written in  module to support browse code------------------------

Option Compare Database

'***************** Code Start **************
'This code was originally written by Ken Getz.
'It is not to be altered or distributed,
'except as part of an application.
'You are free to use it in any application,
'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
'
' Code courtesy of:
' Microsoft Access 95 How-To
' Ken Getz and Paul Litwin
' Waite Group Press, 1996

Type tagOPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    strFilter As String
    strCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    strFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    strFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    strInitialDir As String
    strTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    strDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Declare Function aht_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean

Declare Function aht_apiGetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
Declare Function CommDlgExtendedError Lib "comdlg32.dll" () As Long

Global Const ahtOFN_READONLY = &H1
Global Const ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT = &H2
Global Const ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY = &H4
Global Const ahtOFN_NOCHANGEDIR = &H8
Global Const ahtOFN_SHOWHELP = &H10
' You won't use these.
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLEHOOK = &H20
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLETEMPLATE = &H40
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE = &H80
Global Const ahtOFN_NOVALIDATE = &H100
Global Const ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT = &H200
Global Const ahtOFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT = &H400
Global Const ahtOFN_PATHMUSTEXIST = &H800
Global Const ahtOFN_FILEMUSTEXIST = &H1000
Global Const ahtOFN_CREATEPROMPT = &H2000
Global Const ahtOFN_SHAREAWARE = &H4000
Global Const ahtOFN_NOREADONLYRETURN = &H8000
Global Const ahtOFN_NOTESTFILECREATE = &H10000
Global Const ahtOFN_NONETWORKBUTTON = &H20000
Global Const ahtOFN_NOLONGNAMES = &H40000
' New for Windows 95
Global Const ahtOFN_EXPLORER = &H80000
Global Const ahtOFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS = &H100000
Global Const ahtOFN_LONGNAMES = &H200000


Function ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter As String, _
    strDescription As String, Optional varItem As Variant) As String
' Tack a new chunk onto the file filter.
' That is, take the old value, stick onto it the description,
' (like "Databases"), a null character, the skeleton
' (like "*.mdb;*.mda") and a final null character.

    If IsMissing(varItem) Then varItem = "*.*"
    ahtAddFilterItem = strFilter & _
                strDescription & vbNullChar & _
                varItem & vbNullChar
End Function

Function ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
            Optional ByRef Flags As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal InitialDir As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal Filter As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal FilterIndex As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal DefaultExt As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal filename As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal DialogTitle As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal hWnd As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal OpenFile As Variant) As Variant
' This is the entry point you'll use to call the common
' file open/save dialog. The parameters are listed
' below, and all are optional.
'
' In:
' Flags: one or more of the ahtOFN_* constants, OR'd together.
' InitialDir: the directory in which to first look
' Filter: a set of file filters, set up by calling
' AddFilterItem. See examples.
' FilterIndex: 1-based integer indicating which filter
' set to use, by default (1 if unspecified)
' DefaultExt: Extension to use if the user doesn't enter one.
' Only useful on file saves.
' FileName: Default value for the file name text box.
' DialogTitle: Title for the dialog.
' hWnd: parent window handle
' OpenFile: Boolean(True=Open File/False=Save As)
' Out:
' Return Value: Either Null or the selected filename
Dim OFN As tagOPENFILENAME
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileTitle As String
Dim fResult As Boolean
    ' Give the dialog a caption title.
    If IsMissing(InitialDir) Then InitialDir = CurDir
    If IsMissing(Filter) Then Filter = ""
    If IsMissing(FilterIndex) Then FilterIndex = 1
    If IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = 0&
    If IsMissing(DefaultExt) Then DefaultExt = ""
    If IsMissing(filename) Then filename = ""
    If IsMissing(DialogTitle) Then DialogTitle = ""
    If IsMissing(hWnd) Then hWnd = Application.hWndAccessApp
    If IsMissing(OpenFile) Then OpenFile = True
    ' Allocate string space for the returned strings.
    strFileName = Left(filename & String(256, 0), 256)
    strFileTitle = String(256, 0)
    ' Set up the data structure before you call the function
    With OFN
        .lStructSize = Len(OFN)
        .hwndOwner = hWnd
        .strFilter = Filter
        .nFilterIndex = FilterIndex
        .strFile = strFileName
        .nMaxFile = Len(strFileName)
        .strFileTitle = strFileTitle
        .nMaxFileTitle = Len(strFileTitle)
        .strTitle = DialogTitle
        .Flags = Flags
        .strDefExt = DefaultExt
        .strInitialDir = InitialDir
        ' Didn't think most people would want to deal with
        ' these options.
        .hInstance = 0
        '.strCustomFilter = ""
        '.nMaxCustFilter = 0
        .lpfnHook = 0
        'New for NT 4.0
        .strCustomFilter = String(255, 0)
        .nMaxCustFilter = 255
    End With
    ' This will pass the desired data structure to the
    ' Windows API, which will in turn it uses to display
    ' the Open/Save As Dialog.
    If OpenFile Then
        fResult = aht_apiGetOpenFileName(OFN)
    Else
        fResult = aht_apiGetSaveFileName(OFN)
    End If

    ' The function call filled in the strFileTitle member
    ' of the structure. You'll have to write special code
    ' to retrieve that if you're interested.
    If fResult Then
        ' You might care to check the Flags member of the
        ' structure to get information about the chosen file.
        ' In this example, if you bothered to pass in a
        ' value for Flags, we'll fill it in with the outgoing
        ' Flags value.
        If Not IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = OFN.Flags
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = TrimNull(OFN.strFile)
    Else
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal strItem As String) As String
Dim intPos As Integer
    intPos = InStr(strItem, vbNullChar)
    If intPos > 0 Then
        TrimNull = Left(strItem, intPos - 1)
    Else
        TrimNull = strItem
    End If
End Function
```